# I want to call two observables with the second called after the first one in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I want to call two observables with the second called after the first one.

I have one observable that is subscribed too first.
Then I want the second observable nested within the first observable.

**I want to combine these two subscribes below:**

```
this.serviceA.getData()
.takeUntil(destroyed$)
.subscribe(item => {

});

this.serviceB.getData()
.takeUntil(destroyed$)
.subscribe(item => {

});
```

**This is my attempt showing what I want to do (Updated)**

```
  destroyed$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.serviceA.getData
      .takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      .concatMap(dataA => {
        this.myDataA= dataA;    

        return this.serviceB.getData;
      })
      .takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      .subscribe(dataB => {            

         this.myDataA.forEach(item => {
             item.visible = dataB.find(o => o.id === item.label).isVisible;
         }); 

      });
  };

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  };
```

The aim is to have the nested subscribe called second after the first subscribe because the data is needed from the first subscriber in the second subscribe

Comment: Why don't you use flatMap at RxJS?

Comment: How do you know the first Observable needs always only one second to complete?

Comment: The first call is to get global data. The second call is to show and hide that data on the screen

Comment: I think a forkJoin would be better in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Question (Y),

You need to use `forkJoin` [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md)

> Runs all observable sequences in (parallel) and collect their last elements.

Example:

```js
let character = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1').map(res => res.json());
let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('http://swapi.co/api/planets/1').map(res => res.json());

Observable.forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {
  // results[0] is our character
  // results[1] is our character homeworld
  results[0].homeworld = results[1];
  this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
});
```

Refrence: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

So for your specific case you can do something like:

```js
let obs1 = this.serviceA.getData()
let obs2 = this.serviceB.getData()

Observable.forkJoin([obs1, obs2]).subscribe(results => {
  // results[0] is our obs1
  // results[1] is our obs2
  // show the bigger array
  this.items = results[0] > results[1] ? results[0] : results[1]
});
```

But if you need some data dependent on the other you can do something like

```js
showData() {
  let firstData;
  this.serviceA.getData()
    .map((firstNeededData) => {
      firstData = firstNeededData
      return this.serviceB.getData()
    })
    .subscribe(secondNeededData => {
      // I need to show the bigger 
      this.theBigger = secondNeededData > firstData ? secondNeededData : firstData
    })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the forkJoin, I will try this out. On a side note in the above example is their a way of doing a foreach operator on the this.items rather than a normal js foreach

Comment: can you explain more your question?

Comment: Hi, no I mean in the first subscribe response I want to loop through e.g. foreach on this.items and then use the second subscribes response to update a field in the foreach of this.items

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is incorrect. The `forkJoin` will subscribe to both Observables at the same time while you want to first subscribe to the first one and after it completes subscribe to the second one.

This is typically done using the [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) operator:

```
this.serviceA.getData()
  .concatMap(response => this.serviceB.getData())
  .subscribe(...)
```

If you want to combine the two responses use can use `map` after `serviceB.getData()`.

```
this.serviceA.getData()
  .concatMap(responseA => this.serviceB.getData()
    .map(responseB => /* combine responseA and responseB */ ))
  .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Hi martin, thank you for your answer. I've updated my attempt in my question. Can you have a look and check if it looks correct?

Comment: @martin did you read my full answer? the OP wanted to merge two observables then updated the question to get certain data after another I think `concatMap` is useless in this situation

Comment: @Microsmsm Even after updating the question, you're still wrong and `forkJoin` won't do what OP wants.

Comment: in my answer there's a case that second data is dependant on the first one, am I missing something?

Comment: @Microsmsm Yes, you are. It won't work :) Go ahead and try to run the second example in plnkr/jsbin yourself.

Comment: That's not what OP wanted. With `forkJoin` you're not calling one request after another.